# Can't run Android NDK app on device

Tags: android, crash, android-ndk

I'm trying to start with Android NDK, but I'm in trouble. I've successfully started the 'hello-jni' sample on the Emulator, but the same .apk file doesn't seem to work on the real device, i.e. it says:

> The application HelloJni has stopped unexpectedly.

Any ideas as to what may the cause be?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure that your device has the sufficient version of android for the NDK?

Comment: By Jove, you are right. I might have been using the wrong platform. I'll see and check.

Comment: What version of Android is on the device, what version of NDK do you use and are you using C++ and it's standard library? There are some known-broken combinations.

Comment: Unfortunately, after setting up explicitly that I'm working with a API-8 device (Froyo, that is), I got the same results. Too bad I haven't got a clue.

Comment: @Jan Hudec, I'm using ndkr5 which has got it's own libraries, includes and toolchain.

Comment: @Albus: Hm, than I don't know. The ndkr5 is know to have problems when compiling for older versions, but API level 8 should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is probably an uncaught UnsatisfiedLinkError. In the log around it you should be able to find a line saying something like "libXXX not found" - some dependency library that is missing on your platform.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is two years old, but for completeness:

Looks like you did not build the NDK part of your project. Try the following two lines on your comand line:

```
cd <your_project>
<ndk_root>/ndk-build
```

After that rebuild your project in eclipse.